# Сейчас / сей час. Как правильно?

Tags: грамматика, наречия

> Кандидат на сейчас свободный пост лидера партии... публично призвал
> остановить строительство.

Следовало бы «разбить» обстоятельство времени? Или и в таком виде фраза вполне грамотна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [**Правильное предложение**](https://expert.ru/2020/09/15/spiegel/) выглядит так:

> Что касается правящего CDU, то кандидат на сейчас свободный пост лидера партии и глава парламентского комитета по международным делам Норберт Рётген публично призвал остановить строительство газопровода.

Правильная цитата должна быть такой:
*...кандидат на сейчас свободный пост лидера партии... публично призвал остановить строительство...*

2. В отрыве от контекста предложение выглядит не совсем корректным.
   Возможно было бы такое написание (возможно, если бы это не была политическая статья, в которой обычно архаизмы не используются):
   Что касается правящего CDU, то на сей час кандидат на свободный пост лидера партии и глава парламентского комитета...
3. [Сейчас](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81) в данном случае — это наречие (= на сегодня).
   *Сей час* — это устаревшее указательное местоимение "сей" плюс существительное "час". "Сей" в этом случае можно заменить на "этот": сей (этот) день; сей (этот) год. В нашем предложении такая замена без потери смысла невозможна.

Answer (score 4):

> Следовало бы «разбить» обстоятельство времени? Или и в таком виде
> фраза вполне грамотна?

Грамотна, но не вполне. Вызывает ощущение неправильного использования предлога с наречием, в то время как предлог относится, очевидно, к слову пост: "[кандидат] на пост".

Так что лучше немного поменять, способов много, самый, пожалуй, простой — элементарная перестановка слов: ***кандидат на свободный сейчас пост.***

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, странно объяснять такие вещи, казалось бы очевидные.
Но вот подробный расклад:

С точки зрения правил русской орфографии верным является следующее написание слова: **«СЕЙЧАС»**

Правописание данного слова следует прост запомнить, так как оно является словарным.

**Пример использования слова в речи:**

— Сейчас начнётся шоу.

— Сейчас уже поздно что-либо делать.

— Он сейчас придёт.

[Источник](https://orfogra.ru/kak-pishetsya-sejchas-ili-sej-chas/)